# Вычисление координат центра квадратной области карты

Tags: карты, координаты

Имеются координаты границ квадратной области:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как определить координаты центра этой области?

Comment: Что есть квадрат, что есть координаты, и что есть центр? Квадрат на картинке, очевидно задан в декартовых координатах (Веб Меркатор?). Право/лево/верх/низ даны в географических - долгота/широта, что, вообще-то, квадратом не является.

Answer (score 2):

Если принять за координаты верхней левой точки за (x1, y1), 
а нижней правой за (x2, y2), то координаты центра:

```
(x1 + (x2 - x1) / 2, y2 + (y1 - y2) / 2)
```

Comment: Обычно в квадрате координата центра (по любой оси) равна полусумме координат противолежащих углов. И даже поворот этого не отменяет.